# Write all variable values to a table

Tags: r

I'm a total R-newbie and I have a simple question which might be hilarious but I could not find a answer even though I searched for 4 hours. I might miss the concept.

I write a Monte-Carlo script with a lot of variables stored in differnet environments. At the end of every iteration I want to write all variables (the ones which are listed when typing ls()) to a table.

This would be a working example (without the item I ask for) of what I want to do. (Thank you for your help sofar, it helped me to build that example!)

```
#input data (data will be manipulated for mc later on)
ha<-5
w_eff<-1.9
v_T1<-8
n<-1000 #number of iterations

#function
T1_func <- function(ha_mc, w_eff_mc, v_T1_mc){
    T1_result <- ((ha*10)/(w_eff*v_T1));
    return(T1_result)
    }

for(i in 1:n){ #number of iterations

#MC maipulation (illustrative)
ha_mc<-rnorm(1, ha, sd=1)
w_eff_mc<-rnorm(1, w_eff, sd=1)
v_T1_mc<-rnorm(1, v_T1, sd=1)


#calculation
T1_mc<-T1_func(ha_mc, w_eff_mc, v_T1_mc)

#now I want to write all variables to a table
df<-data.frame(ha, w_eff, v_T1, ha_mc, w_eff_mc, v_T1_mc, T1_mc)
write.table(df, file = "result.txt", append = TRUE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
        eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = FALSE,
        col.names = !file.exists("result.txt"), qmethod = c("escape", "double"))
}
```

My question would be: how do I get that:

```
df<-data.frame(ha, w_eff, v_T1, ha_mc, w_eff_mc, v_T1_mc, T1_mc)
```

without writing down all the variables (ha, w_eff, v_T1, ha_mc, w_eff_mc, v_T1_mc, T1_mc) but with something like "ls()". And how do I get that for the variables in the different environments so that I will have a column named "my.env$w_eff".

Thank you very much!

Comment: Put them in a data.frame and you'll have no problem.

Comment: ok, thank you! I.e,
b<-"a manual list of all variables"
a<-data.frame (b)
?
But is there a way like data.frame(ls())

Comment: I think you want the data and the headers together.

Comment: I would like to generate a table with a header line  and results of each iteration in a separate line.  I just don't understand how to do that and do not know what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the solution I found with your help, thx!

```
write_table_func <- function(env_name, file_part_name, dir_name){
#write input to table
df_input<-data.frame(as.list(get(env_name), all.names=TRUE))
sort.df_input <- df_input[,order(names(df_input))]

  filename<-(paste(sep="", dir_name, "/", "tabl_", process_n, "_", process_step_n, file_part_name, ".txt"));
  suppressWarnings(write.table(sort.df_input, file = paste(filename), append = TRUE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
              eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = FALSE,
              col.names = !file.exists(paste(filename)), qmethod = c("escape", "double")));
  rm(df_input);
  rm(sort.df_input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I woud suggest not using `ls()` and instead making a `data.frame` which contains the variables you want to store. Here I firstly create the file `"results.txt"` with the correct column headers (I'm storing values of `a`, `b`, and `c`) and then in each iteration I append the corresponding values to the file. Hope this helps:

```
n <- 10L
write.table(data.frame("a", "b", "c"), file = "result.txt", 
        col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    #do MC

    a <- rnorm(1L)
    b <- exp(a)
    c <- a + b

    write.table(data.frame(a, b, c), file = "result.txt", 
            append = TRUE, row.names = i, col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is it possible to automatically generate a data frame of all variables in the enviroment (that would save me an enormous amount of work), I think. I will have about 100 variables which will differ in every calculation.

Comment: I think you might need to post an example of your code and an example of how you want the output to look. Is your code generating variables using `assign("a", 1)` or something? It will probably be (a lot) easier to store your results in a vector (which can have variable length).